# Function doesn't return a value on all code paths Vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, string, delegates, vb.net-2010

I'm somewhat new to programming and I am having trouble just making this work.  I'm supposed to run this code using a delegate but I've run into error after error.  I'm using Vb.net.  Could anyone help me solve the issues in this code?

```
Public Delegate Function D()
Dim Str As String = Console.ReadLine()
Sub Main()
    Dim D1 As D
    D1 = New D(AddressOf Fn1)
End Sub
Function Fn1()
    System.Console.WriteLine("Please enter the string")

    Dim revstr As String = StrReverse(Str)
    Console.WriteLine("Reverse:")
    Console.WriteLine(revstr)

    Console.WriteLine("Amount of characters in the string:")
    Dim Count As Integer = Str.Length
    Console.WriteLine(Count)

    Console.WriteLine("Amount of words in the string:")
    Dim TempA() As String = Str.Split(" ")
    Console.WriteLine(TempA.Length & " ")
    Console.ReadKey()
End Function
```

Thanks for any help anyone can give!

Comment: Not *directly* to do with your question, but I recommend that you set [Option Strict On](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) as the default setting for new projects.

Comment: Coult you post the errors as well?

Comment: Function 'Fn1' doesn't return a value on all code paths. A null reference exception could occur at run time when the result is used.

Comment: If i switch it from a function to a sub i get this: Method 'Public Sub Fn1()' does not have a signature compatible with delegate 'Delegate Function D() As Object'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Function Fn1 doesn't return anything.

Functions by definition return something. If you want a method that doesn't return anything you should declare it `Sub` instead of `Function`

Your function should also declare the data type is is returning:

```
Public Function Concat(s1 As String, s2 As String) As String
    return s1 & s2
End Function
```

Comment: I had it as a sub earlier but i get an error saying that the method and the delegate don't have compatible signatures.

Comment: Your delegate needs to be either a Function or a Sub depending on what type of method Fn1 is

Comment: I switched the delegate to a sub along with the method but now nothing in the delegate runs.  The global readline runs but then it closes.

Comment: Thats another question but the answer is that you don't actually do anything with D1 after you have specified the address. Try adding `D1.Invoke`

Comment: Thank you so much for the help its pretty much working how i want it now!